# Custom My account page and custom page for editing posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy

I have created WP theme for property company, with custom post types which are actually apartments so users can from one custom page enter all the informations and the custom post gets saved.

I would like to now display custom pages for "My account" and "Edit apartments" options. So is there a way to do a custom my acc and custom page for editing post?

I cant find much on google, can someone help?

Comment: What about the [WP User Frontend Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/) ?

Comment: It will help me, thanks! I will explain below how to edit some settings on custom fields..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Wp User Frontend Plugin works for displaying Profile page, and Edit post page for registered users on site.

Plugin lets you create "Dashobard page" where users can see all of their published posts and have Edit option for each of them.

You can also Add new fields on your forms, and then display "Edit page" or "Add new page" template via plugin.

If you already have your own custom fields, and want to enable your users to edit them via Plugin front end "Edit page" under dashboard, the process would be:

1. Find custom-fields.php (inside plugins/wpfrontend/admin), and delete four prefixes containing cf_
2. Go to Custom fields sections of the plugin, inside your dashboard and add custom fields that have exact **field name** as your existing custom fields.

You will see that when registered users edit fields under dashboard>edit post on the plugin front end, that your existing fields on custom posts gets updated.

Thanks to the creator, this is really useful plugin!

Regards

Josip